# Как настроить service-worker для кэширования и шаблонов с домена и статики с поддомена

Tags: reactjs, поддомены, pwa, service-worker

Пытаюсь запилить pwa из ssr сайта на реакте. Шаблоны отдаются нодой. Сайт лежит по адресу https://m.my.site.ru, а статика на https://my-static.site.ru.
Добавляю service worker в корень, соотвтетствено он будет лежать в https://my-static.site.ru/service-worker.js

И я не могу понять каким образом зарегистрировать воркер.

`navigator.serviceWorker.register('https://my-static.site.ru/service-worker.js')` - ругается на:

```
Error during service worker registration: DOMException: Failed to register a ServiceWorker: The origin of the provided scriptURL ('https://my-static.site.ru) does not match the current origin ('https://m.my.site.ru').
```

Можно в принципе помучиться и заставить ноду отдавать https://m.my.site.ru/service-worker.js, но это не особо красиво.

Я бы хотел, чтобы сайт на телефоне походил на  приложение, то есть открывал сразу страничку, с каркасом, заменяющим контент, который затем подгружу динамически (кэшировал и шаблон страницы `/games` и статику с `https://my-static.site.ru/bundle.min.js`, `https://my-static.site.ru/styles.min.js`)

Либо я неправильно понял как оно всё должно работать.